# Gem install behind NTLM proxy

Tags: ruby, proxy, rubygems

When I try
`gem install bundler`

```
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (URI::InvalidURIError)
bad URI(is not URI?): https://username:password@202.141.80.24:3128/
```

The same happens for other installations through gems.

There is no particular problem with the environment variables as other terminal utilities like `apt-get` that use internet through this proxy work just fine.

Comment: https://github.com/rubygems/rubygems/issues/360
  This issue was closed in 2012 with a conclusion that gems doesn't support NTLM proxy.But its 3 years ago. Has a solution been developed for this ?